# How to solve problem downloading R-Markdown .html files from shiny app deployed online?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinyapps

I have been trying to create a shiny application to make annual reporting of final exam reports at our school more professional and consistent across teacher/subjects, and potentially schools within the municipality.

The app is supposed to allow the user to upload an excel file, specify parameters and generate an R-Markdown document (.html), rendered from a markdown script I have been using for years, display the .html, and allow the user to download it to their local drive. Currently my code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)   
library(car)      
library(huxtable)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(ape)
library(kableExtra)
library(plotly)
library(broom)
library(rstatix)
library(corrplot)
library(matrixcalc)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(fmsb)
library(ggradar)
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(psych)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Exam statistics tool"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload your file"),
      textInput("year", "Year", ""),
      textInput("season", "Season", ""),
      textInput("center", "Center", ""),
      textInput("school", "School", ""),
      textInput("level", "Level", ""),
      textInput("subj", "Subject", ""),
      actionButton("generate", "Generate Report"),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Report")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Output elements (e.g., report preview)
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive values
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    excelData = NULL,
    reportHTML = NULL
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    # Read the uploaded Excel file and perform validation
    rv$excelData <- readxl::read_excel(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$generate, {
    # Show a progress bar
    withProgress(message = "Generating report...", value = 0, {
      # Generate the report based on the uploaded data and parameters

      reportData <- data.frame(
        Year = input$year,
        Season = input$season,
        Center = input$center,
        School = input$school,
        Level = input$level,
        Subj = input$subj,
        Data = rv$excelData
      )
      
      # Render the report using R Markdown
      rv$reportHTML <- rmarkdown::render(
        input = "report/VPREP_9.Rmd",
        output_format = "html_document",
        output_file = tempfile(fileext = ".html"),
        params = list(
          year = input$year,
          season = input$season,
          center = input$center,
          school = input$school,
          level = input$level,
          subj = input$subj
        )
      )
      
      # Update the progress bar
      incProgress(1, detail = "Report generated!")
    })
  })
  
  # Render the report preview
  output$preview <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(rv$reportHTML)) {
      HTML(paste0("<iframe src='", rv$reportHTML, "' style='width:100%; height:600px'></iframe>"))
    }
  })
  
  # Download the report
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    if (!is.null(rv$reportHTML)) {
      file.copy(rv$reportHTML, "report.html", overwrite = TRUE)
      file.rename("report.html", "www/report.html")
    }
  })
}

# Create a standalone app
app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the app locally, directly from RStudio, the .html is not displayed, and the download button doesn't work, however, the generated .html is saved locally in the temp folder on drive C automatically. Hence I know the app correctly renders the .html. When I deploy the app online through shinyapps.io, it displays the same behavior, except when I click "download", an .html file containing the interface of the app (with the text fields where parameters can be specified) is downloaded instead of the markdown report. The progress bar completes as intended. I checked the logs on shinyapps.io which show that the markdown renders as intended, and the .html report is saved to a temporary folder on the server. However, it neither displays nor can be downloaded.

I would appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the help page of the function downloadButton/downloadHandler

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will try to implement it and report back. This, however, does not explain why the report does not even get displayed in the browser. Do you have any ideas about that as well?